# DataClasses in Kotlin - Overriding the equals() from 'Any' Class

Tags: kotlin, equals, data-class

I've been working on overriding the equals() from Any class. But in the below code. I'm confused why
"if (other is Person)" is necessary to get the "if(this.firstName == **other.firstName**)" statement to work.

```
fun main()
{
 var personObj1 = Person("Adam","S")
 var personObj2 = Person("Adam","S")
 println(personObj1.equals(personObj2))

}

class Person(var firstName:String, var lastName:String)
{

    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
       if (other is Person) {
            if (this.firstName == other.firstName) {
                return true
            }
        }
        return  false
    }

}
```

Without the if(other is Person) statement, code gives the below error

[image]

Comment: Because `other` is type `Any?`, which doesn't have a `firstName` property. Doing `if (other is Person)` allows the compiler to perform a [smart cast](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/typecasts.html#smart-casts) to `Person`, which _does_ have a `firstName` property.

Comment: As an additional note, you mentioned data classes in the question title, but you aren't using one. Kotlin has actual `data class` types that give you an `equals` implementation for free.

Answer (score 2):

**Short Answer:**

`other` is of type `Any?`, the check for `other is Person` [smartcasts](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/typecasts.html#smart-casts) it to `Person`, which makes the `firstName` property available.

**Long Answer:**
A few things to note about this question and the code:

1. The title and the tags mention "data class". If you were to actually use `data class`, `equals` and `hashCode` are generated automatically and you don't have to implement them. Check [the documentation about data classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/data-classes.html) to find out whether they are applicable in your situation (they probably are).
2. **Always** override `hashCode()` *IF* you manually override `equals()` and vice versa. Not doing so can lead to serious performance problems or even bugs when using hash-based data structures like `HashMap` or `HashSet`. Again, if you're using `data class`, no need to worry about this.
3. As a rule of thumb in Kotlin, *always* use `val` instead of `var` up to the point where it doesn't work anymore (because you have to reassign it). Using `var` can disable smart casts in a lot of situations and therefore make your code less elegant. In your example, all occurrences of `var` can most likely be swapped out for `val`.
4. Just as you're using the `==` operator to check whether `this.firstName` is equal to `other.firstName`, you can (and should) use `==` to compare `personObj1` and `personObj2` in your `main` function. See [operator overloading](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/operator-overloading.html#equality-and-inequality-operators).
5. You should always simplify statements in the form of

```kotlin
if (something) {
    return true
} else {
    return false
}
```

to just

```kotlin
return something
```

In your snippet, there's no `else` branch, but still the implementation could be simplified to

```kotlin
override fun equals(other: Any?) = (other is Person) && (firstName == other.firstName)
```

(see also: [expression functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/functions.html#single-expression-functions))

6. Make sure to follow the [official Kotlin coding conventions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coding-conventions.html) as your style guide for formatting and the like, in order to ensure readability. IntelliJ already has this style guide integrated and can automatically format all source files for you.